# Ionic Cordova plugins cannot be found in ios (xcode console)

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cordova, ionic2

I often had the issue that the ios or android emulator cannot find the cordova plugins, even though they are installed. When I try to install a plugin again, cordova throws an error:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-device': Error: Uh oh!
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/Users/student/Desktop/wts/WTS/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js'
```

This is a very popular Error, because it happens with all the cordova plugins. Even when I try to uninstall a plugin it throws an error, but nonetheless removes it. Sometimes when I'm lucky, I can remove all plugins, reinstall them again and everything works. But I'm really tired of doing this so many times. Ionic used to a have a command for reinstalling all plugins with `ionic state reset`, this is deprecated and I could not find another alternative. Is there an easy way to remove and reinstall existing plugins? I don't want to do this for each plugin separately.